# Node Promise with Local Variable

Tags: promise

```
async function A(){
 const x = await B(); // reads a file or such thing
 return x; // returns a promise
}
var foo; 
function setFoo(){
   foo = A(); // foo will be set to the promise returned by A()
              // but I really want foo to be set to the data 
              // returned by the promise
}
function C(){
// here I need to use the value of the data returned 
// by the promise. There are dozens of functions that 
// will use foo. Those dozens of functions are called 
// from outside of this module
}
```

Question - Is there some way to extract the data from the promise so I can use it in a local variable? Or do I need to use promise semantics i.e .then(function(...){...}) in every function like function C that needs to use the local variable foo? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `async` in a function that does nothing other than `return await`. Just `return` the promise and you're done.

```
function A() {
  return B(); // reads a file or such thing, returns a promise
}
```

Never try to set global/outer-scope variables to capture asynchronous values. Keep returning the promises, chain in worker functions with `.then()`. Keep returning the promise chain.

```
function foo(){
  return A().then(C);
}
```

The worker functions (an event handler, really) receive the data:

```
function C(data) {
  // here you get the data returned by B()
}
```

You could even wait for `C()` now:

```
foo().then(function (x) {
  // `C()` ans finished and `x` will be whatever `C()` returned.
})
```

Comment: Yes, I see that. But that means in order to use any data returned eventually by the promise returned by function A I would need to have .then() clauses in every single method that needs to touch any part of that data. Correct? Seems anti-pattern-ish?

Comment: @DThompson55 No, only in the function that waits for `A()`'s result, here `foo()`. In the function that *uses* `A()`'s result, here `C()`, it's a completely regular value. If you want to write code that looks more like synchronous code ("waiting for" and "using" within the same function), you're free to move to `async`/`await`.